# Full screen Masonry theme that works with every Screen Resolution?

Tags: jquery, screen, fullscreen, jquery-masonry, calculated-columns

Basically I want to make a Masonry theme that will have a set amount of columns such as like 5, and the width of each column (post) will be calculated by the screen size.

I am unsure on how to go about doing this, I already read about the Masonry documentation and whatnot and can't find anything helpful. If you could help that be amazing! Thank you!

Heres my masonry coding so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
var $content = $('#posts');
$content.masonry({itemSelector: '.entry'}),
$content.infinitescroll({
navSelector : 'div#pagination', 
nextSelector : 'div#pagination a#nextPage', 
itemSelector : '.entry',
loading: {
finishedMsg: '',
img: 'http://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/pX1lrx8xv/ajax-loader.gif'
},
bufferPx : 600,
debug : false,
},
// call masonry as a callback.
function( newElements ) {
var $newElems = $( newElements );
$newElems.hide();
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$content.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true, function(){$newElems.fadeIn(300);} );
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use CSS to set the column width? Masonry will work based on the width of the columns. `.column{width:20%}` (no margin, no padding inc)

Comment: It doesn't really get the effect I want. I just want masonry to fill the entire screen no matter the screen size. :/

Comment: masonry will only effect the area `#posts` has.

Comment: For this, you need to use http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html